# Dropdown menu not working

Tags: menu-bar

The dropdown menus in my installation of Emacs 24.3.1 are not working anymore. Pressing F10 or `M-x menu-bar-open` opens the menu in a text buffer. I really miss the graphical dropdown menu in text mode.

The issue seems related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158320/file-edit-options-etc-menus-dont-work-on-emacs-23-any-ideas), but that thread reports a bug on OS X Emacs while I'm using Ubuntu.

As for my `.emacs` file: it only had a couple of commands from [emacs-for-python](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python)

```
(load-file "/home/erickrf/.emacs.d/emacs-for-python/epy-init.el")
(epy-setup-ipython)
```

I deleted everything from the file, but to no help. The dropdown doesn't appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The dropdown menus in my installation of Emacs 24.3.1 are not working anymore.

Upgrade to Emacs 24.4 for the dropdown menus feature.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem... I got used to an Emacs installation in another machine.