# Menu bar drop-downs empty

Tags: yasnippet, elpy, menu-bar, emacs25

I am using Emacs 25.3.2 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is that several of the menu bar items produce empty drop-downs. A grey box appears, but with nothing inside. It looks like this:

[image]

I originally noticed this happening for the `YASnippet`, `Python` and `Virtual Envs` and after playing around a lot with various modes, saving, closing, restarting Emacs and so on, I believe it is always specific to the current mode. The `File`, `Edit`, `Options` and `Buffers` tabs never seem to have a problem.

Pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> seems to reset something and then everything works again, but after some time (I haven't been able to determine when/why exactly), the mode-relevant menu bar tabs seems to once again be empty.

#### Any clues as to what might be causing this?

I have seen [this problem](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18202/dropdown-menu-not-working), but it appears to have been version specific and also a different issue to mine.

Comment: Does this also happen when you run Emacs without any user settings, so by running `emacs -Q` and manually loading `YASnippet` or any one of the other modes in which you've encountered this?

Comment: No. I am unable to reproduce it by starting with `emacs - Q` and then loading in `elpy` or `yasnippet`. Although I haven't been able to pinpoint when it happens *with* my configuration. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. This works for me.

ref:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-gtk/+bug/673302

In ~/.bashrc  export the UBUNTU_MENU_PROXY variable

```
export UBUNTU_MENU_PROXY=emacs
```

Source you .bashrc file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Open a terminal and launch emacs

Comment: this seems to work, but how can it be applied so that starting emacs from the launcher also picks up on the env var? I suppose setting all windows to have their dropdown settings on the frame, system-wide, should do it - even without exporting that env var.

Comment: There's a transcription mistake or misunderstanding here - the command from the original was `UBUNTU_MENU_PROXY= emacs` - ie run the command `emacs` with the overridden environment variable set to the empty string

Answer (score 0):

Robert Birkelbach, in "Dealing with empty menus in GNU Emacs", gave a simple fix that seems to work, namely add the following to your .emacs:

```lisp
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode 1)
```

Why turning menus off and then back on would do the trick is not so clear... :-)